# Cannot see the right and used space on a ZFS dataset

Tags: linux, storage, zfs, zpool

I have set up a vm with debian buster and ZFS. Initially the machine booted from first hard drive, but added x4 20Gb hd and transfered the system to zfs for testing purposes.

It works, so I added some datasets to see how it grows. But when querying about the used / free space it does not show the real numbers. It seems nothing happened. Also tested reaching the quota and the result is the same,

What i am doing wrong ?

Thanks.

The disk layout

```
root@debzfs:~# fdisk -l | grep sd | sort
/dev/sda1      2048 40892415 40890368 19.5G Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sda9  40892416 41943006  1050591  513M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb1      2048 40892415 40890368 19.5G Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdb9  40892416 41943006  1050591  513M BIOS boot
/dev/sdc1      2048 40892415 40890368 19.5G Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdc9  40892416 41943006  1050591  513M BIOS boot
/dev/sdd1      2048 40892415 40890368 19.5G Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdd9  40892416 41943006  1050591  513M BIOS boot
Disk /dev/sda: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Disk /dev/sdb: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Disk /dev/sdc: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Disk /dev/sdd: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
```

The root pool and dataset (where the original system has been copied)

```
zpool create -d -o feature@async_destroy=enabled -o feature@empty_bpobj=enabled -o feature@lz4_compress=enabled -o ashift=12 -O compression=lz4 rpool raidz2 /dev/sd[a-d]1 -f
zfs create rpool/root
zfs set quota=10gb rpool/root

# The new datasets
zfs create rpool/smalldb
zfs set quota=5gb rpool/smalldb
zfs create rpool/greatdb
zfs set quota=20gb rpool/greatdb
```

Current disk layout after creating datasets

```
root@debzfs:~# zpool status
  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool. The pool can
        still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
        the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
        the features. See zpool-features(5) for details.
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        rpool       ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sda1    ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdb1    ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdc1    ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdd1    ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

root@debzfs:~# zpool list
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
rpool  77.5G  3.04G  74.5G         -      -     3%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
root@debzfs:~# zfs list
NAME            USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool          1.47G  34.9G   244K  /rpool
rpool/greatdb   198K  20.0G   198K  /rpool/greatdb
rpool/root     1.47G  8.53G  1.47G  /
rpool/smalldb   198K  5.00G   198K  /rpool/smalldb
```

Test commands and output (wrong).
Expected current size and free space. But it seems nothing happened.

```
truncate -s 2G /rpool/smalldb/smalldb.log
truncate -s 8G /rpool/smalldb/limitdb.log      #what ? if ls the file is there !!
truncate -s 10G /rpool/greatdb/greatdb.log

root@debzfs:~# zpool list
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
rpool  77.5G  3.03G  74.5G         -      -     3%  1.00x  ONLINE  -

root@debzfs:~# zfs list
NAME            USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool          1.47G  34.9G   244K  /rpool
rpool/greatdb   209K  20.0G   209K  /rpool/greatdb
rpool/root     1.47G  8.53G  1.47G  /
rpool/smalldb   209K  5.00G   209K  /rpool/smalldb

root@debzfs:~# ls -lh /rpool/smalldb/ /rpool/greatdb/
/rpool/greatdb/:
total 512
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10G Nov  4 00:11 greatdb.log

/rpool/smalldb/:
total 1.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.0G Nov  4 00:14 limitdb.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.0G Nov  4 00:09 smalldb.log
root@debzfs:~#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not use truncate**. This creates a file full of null bytes. The null bytes do not consume any disk space, **the file is a sparse file**. Watch out with `/dev/zero` also.

Use any other method. `dd`,`head` or you fave python script. **But do not create a sparse file.**